# Сложное предложение с "пусть"

Tags: запятые

Верно ли, что не требуется запятая в предложении:
«Пусть мечты сбудутся и исполнятся все желания», так как есть общее слово?

Comment: Дополнительная информация: Галочку и лайк (верхний серый треугольник) можно комбинировать. На этом сайте уже, можно сказать, сложилась такая традиция.

Comment: Олеся, Вы принимаете ответы галочкой – это хорошо. Но почему-то не отмечаете их стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх. Поощрять таким образом можно и нужно все полезные ответы и вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. Абсолютно верно. Вы правы. Запятая там совсем не в тему.

Пример Розенталя:
*Пусть кончится холод и наступит тепло!* — объединяет побудительная частица.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133